# React if statement not showing result

Tags: reactjs

In React i have a button that when clicked will decrement state object value by one. When state value is decremented to 0, it should activate alert method but for some reason it only activates after state value one has reached to -1 not 0.
 Any help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';



class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {

      numbers:{
        one:1
      },

    };

  }


  decrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        numbers:{
          ...prevState.numbers,
          one: prevState.numbers.one - 1
        }

      }
    }, () => console.log(
            this.state.numbers.one,

      ));

      if(this.state.numbers.one===0){
        alert('test');
       }

  }

  render() {


    return (
      <div className="App">
         <div>{this.state.numbers.one}</div> 

          <br/>
          <button onClick={this.decrement}>ok</button>     
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Set State is async, you need to wait for the state change or use a lifecycle method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i was saying in the comments. `setState` is async, you need to wait for the state change or use a lifecycle method.

So in your decrement function you can alert in the callback you are already using, which has the updated state value there.

```
decrement = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      numbers:{
        ...prevState.numbers,
        one: prevState.numbers.one - 1
      }
    }
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.numbers.one) 
    if(this.state.numbers.one===0){
      alert('test');
    }
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to check this value

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.numbers.one > 0 && this.state.numbers.one === 0) {
    alert('test');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `setState` is async, you need to add the alert in the call back of `setState`.

```
class App extends Component {  
    constructor(props){
      super(props);    
      this.state = {    
          numbers:{
            one:1
          },    
      };    
    }

    decrement = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                numbers:{
                    ...prevState.numbers,
                    one: prevState.numbers.one - 1
                }    
            }
        }, 
        () => {
            console.log(this.state.numbers.one)    
            if(this.state.numbers.one===0){
                alert('test');
            }
        });    
    }

    render() {        
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div>{this.state.numbers.one}</div>     
                <br/>
                <button onClick={this.decrement}>ok</button>     
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

you could implement the decrement function as below

```
decrement = () => {
    this.setState({numbers: { ...this.state.numbers, one: this.state.numbers.one -1} },
        () => {
            this.state.numbers.one===0 && alert("test")
        }
    )

}
```